# Every quantifier free formula defines a set with finitely many connected components?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I was trying to prove this claim:

"Every quantifier-free formula $\psi (x, a_1, ...a_m)$, where $a_1,...,a_m \in \mathbb{R}$, defines a set with finitely many connected components."

In other words, a set that is a finite union of points and open intervals.

I'm just starting to study logic so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In what language is the formula $\psi$ defined?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify it clearly - it's in the language of the ordered ring of real numbers $\{+,-,\cdot,0,1\}$.

Comment: By a theorem of Tarski, not only quantifier free formulas do this, but *every* formula $\phi(x)$ in that language defines a set of reals which is a finite union of intervals and points. The proof for quantifier free formulas is the easiest part of that result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: first look at the sets defined by the atomic formulas. If $\psi$ is atomic it has the form $f(x) = g(x)$ where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in $x$ and the set defined by $\psi$ is either the whole real line or a (possibly empty) finite set of points, so what you are trying to prove is true for atomic $\psi$. Now show that if your claim holds for $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, then it also holds for $\lnot \psi_1$, $\psi_1 \land \psi_2$ and $\psi_1 \lor \psi_2$ (which amounts to showing that the set of all subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ comprising a finite set of points and intervals is closed under complements, unions and intersections).

Comment: Yes. This is in the language of an ordered ring, so there are also atomic formulas $f(x) < g(x)$, which still define a finite set of intervals.

Comment: @Carl: I was following coffeemaker's comment which gives a signature that does not include $<$ (which is not needed for the reals since it is definable). But if it is included in the signature, then, as you say, it doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: The OP does say "the language of the ordered ring of real numbers" and did not specify *any* relation symbols in the signature (not even equality).

Comment: Yes, but (like nearly everybody), I consider equality to be a logical symbol unless the context is very explicit that I should not do so.